# How to return IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone tell me how I can return an `IQueryable<T>`?

I am getting :

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<object>` to
>   `System.Linq.IQueryable<TType>`. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

Thank you in advance

Code:

```
public IQueryable<TType> ExecuteScript<TType>(string script, object parameters) where TType : class, new()
{
        string typeName = String.Empty;

        LuaScript lScript = LuaScript.Prepare(script);
        var lLScript = lScript.Load(Context.Server());

        //Converts returned result into a string array. 
        var result = (string[])lLScript.Evaluate(Context.Database(), parameters); 

        if (result.Any())
        {
            _dataValue = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
            int i=0;

            while(i < result.Count())
            {
                _dataValue.Add(result[i], result[i+=1]);
                i++;
            }
        }

        IQueryable<object> query = _dataValue.AsQueryable().Select(r => r.Value);            

        return query;                    
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to return `IQueryable<T>`? The data is in memory so why not make it `IEnumerable<T>`? There are exceedingly few reasons to ever call `.AsQueryable()`.

Answer (score 5):

You try to return `IQueryable<object>` from:

```
IQueryable<object> query = _dataValue.AsQueryable().Select(r => r.Value);            
return query;
```

But function return type is `IQueryable<TType>` from:

```
public IQueryable<TType> ExecuteScript<TType>(string script, object parameters) where TType : class, new()
```

Try:

```
IQueryable<TType> query = _dataValue.AsQueryable().Select(r => r.Value);            
return query;
```